# Methods to Find Kth minimum number in pandas dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, series

Given a dataframe with m rows and n columns, I want the column name of minimum in each row. I am using a for loop. Next, I perform a test with the column obtained, if the test fails, I want the second minimum in the same row, and so on.

My current code sorts the dataframe for each row. Of course, the first value is minimum. I perform the test. If test is failed I go to second value and so on. The code is attached below. `data` and `dfObj` are pandas dataframe objects.

```
for i in data.index:                                                #for each row
    dfObj = data.sort_values(by = i, axis=1, ascending = True)      #sorting by row and saving as new dataframe
    for column in dfObj:                                             # looping over column in sorted dataframe
         if some_condition true:
              perform action
          else:
              continue                                               # this takes me to next column
```

However, this approach is very slow and inefficient. This is sorting entire dataframe m times. If possible I would like to do this without sorting. Is there better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide an example of your input and output dataframes.

Comment: what do you perform really on the data per row?

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding sorting at each row, you can vectorize this with [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html?highlight=argsort#numpy-argsort)

```
#data
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=25).reshape(-1,5), 
                    columns=list('abcde'))

#your method
for i in data.index:
    dfObj = data.sort_values(by = i, axis=1, ascending = True)
    print (i, dfObj.columns)
# 0 Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')
# 1 Index(['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e'], dtype='object')
# 2 Index(['d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
# 3 Index(['b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e'], dtype='object')
# 4 Index(['c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'a'], dtype='object')

#vectorize way
print (data.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(data.to_numpy())])
# [['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']
#  ['a' 'c' 'd' 'b' 'e']
#  ['d' 'e' 'a' 'b' 'c']
#  ['b' 'd' 'a' 'c' 'e']
#  ['c' 'b' 'e' 'd' 'a']]
```